# Using Macros in DBT Model

Tags: postgresql, dbt

I have created a simple model using one macros. Below are the macro and the model
macros/get_customer_teritary.sql

```
{% macro get_customer_teritary(customer_id) %}
    {% set v_sql  %}
        SELECT territoryid
        FROM sales.customer
        WHERE customerid  =  {{ customer_id }} ;
    {% endset %}
    {{log("SQL to run :" ~ v_sql, info=True)}}
    {% set result = run_query(v_sql) %}

    {% if execute %}
        {{ log("results " ~ result.columns[0].values()[0], info=True ) }}
        {% set v_tr_id = result.columns[0].values()[0] %}
    {% else %}
        {% set v_tr_id = NULL %}

    {% endif %}

    {{ return(v_tr_id) }}
    
{% endmacro %}
```

model/sales_orders.sql

```
select salesorderid , 
    orderdate , 
    status,
    customerid ,
    {{ log("calling for customerid: " ~ customerid , info=True ) }}
    {{ get_customer_teritary(customerid) }} as customer_teritary_id
from sales.salesorderheader
```

When executed, the macro is not receiving any value, Below is the log, expected output is to have 10 distinct tertiary ids, but getting tertiary id as 1 for all records.

```
dbt show --profiles-dir "C:\Users\dbt-1\.dbt" --inline "SELECT customer_teritary_id,count(*) FROM {{ ref('sales_orders') }} GROUP BY customer_teritary_id"

11:04:27  Running with dbt=1.7.3
11:04:28  Registered adapter: postgres=1.7.3
11:04:28  **calling for customerid:** 
11:04:28  SQL to run :
        SELECT territoryid
        FROM sales.customer
        **WHERE customerid  =   ;**

11:04:28  Found 1 model, 0 sources, 0 exposures, 0 metrics, 402 macros, 0 groups, 0 semantic models
11:04:28  
11:04:28  Concurrency: 1 threads (target='dev')
11:04:28  
11:04:28  Previewing inline node:
| customer_teritary_id | count |
| -------------------- | ----- |
|                    1 | 31465 |
```

As suggested in few threads, tried enclosing customerid in ', ", ` while calling the macro from model but nothing helped.

Using dbt with postgres adapter.

Comment: You can't use the results of a model as a value to pass into a macro. DBT runs are primarily a 2 step process. The first runs the Jinja compilation and the second runs the model. During the first run is also when call statements are executed, so the query you're trying to run in the macro is executed before the query in the model.

Comment: I'm not sure if this example just for an example or the actual problem, but if it is... You might want to use a join?

Comment: This is just for an example to make use of macros.